# Sum identical item id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

How to get the sum of quantity based on `item_id`? I have item_id identical in the `tableThreeItems` table which I want to get the sum of quantity, the quantity values are 4 and 40. The problem with my code is always returning 4 which it should be 44.

```
<!-- TableOne.php -->
public function tableTwoItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TableTwoItems::class);
}

<!-- TableTwoItem.php -->
public function tableOne()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TableOne::class);
}

public function tableThreeItems(){
    return $this->hasMany(TableThreeItem::class);
}

<!-- TableThreeItem.php -->
public function tableTwoItem()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TableTwoItem::class);
}
```

**Code:**

```
public static function getItemSumForProcessing(int $itemId): int
{
    $tableRelationship = 'tableTwoItems.tableThreeItems';

    $item = self::with([$tableRelationship])
        ->where('status_id', Statuses::FOR_APPROVAL)
        ->whereHas($tableRelationship, function ($query) use ($itemId) {
            $query->where('item_id', $itemId);
        })
        ->first();

    if (!$item) {
        return 0;
    }

    $total = $item->tableTwoItems->flatMap(function ($item) use ($itemId) {
        return $item->tableThreeItems->where('item_id', $itemId);
    });

    return $total->sum('quantity');
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424987

Comment: change query to match with your requirements.